# How should I delimit between the valid input and the shellcode for my buffer overflow?

Tags: c, scanf, delimiter, buffer-overflow, null-terminated

I was given a program for an assignment and told to do a buffer overflow on it. My professor has configured the VM we are working on to execute shellcode on the stack, so I only need to place the start of shellcode into the return address. The buffer I am trying to overflow is `s1[64]`. `s1` should be a valid filename as it is used later on in the program and will cause the program to `exit(1)` if it is invalid. I am assuming that I should fill `s1` with input in this format :
`validFileName+fileNameTerminator+Filler+Shellcode`.

`S1` is read in from the command line using `scanf(%s,s1)`. The issue I'm having is that no matter what I choose to place between my valid file name and the start of my filler and shellcode, the program thinks the whole input is the filename and fails to open it. I have tried with short file names and 63 and 64 length file names, all give the same result. 
For example: If I give the input for `s1` as `/./././././././././././././././././././././././testFile1GCL.txt\0AAAAAAAA\xeb\x18\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x76\x08\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x1e\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68` 
I am expecting the value in `s1` to be `/./././././././././././././././././././././././testFile1GCL.txt` as it is long enough to fill the entire buffer and is followed by null terminator. The issue is that when I have `s1` printed out, it prints the whole input as if it isn't seeing the null terminator and is obviously looking outside of its given range. This then causes the program to fault because that giant thing obviously isn't a valid file name.

I have tried almost everything I can think of to put between the filename and the rest of my payload, including `\\0` `\0` `0x0` `0x90`. No matter what, the program always thinks `s1` is the whole long input and fails. Even if it isn't recognizing the terminator, why is it even looking outside of the 64 characters allotted to `s1`?

EDIT: I have now tried putting a space between the file name and rest of the payload and that keeps the file from exiting, but only because scanf stops at the space and isnt' reading in the rest of the payload

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a file like `/tmp/{shellcode here}`. Even if your FS doesn't support files with names containing some bytes from the shellcode you have chosen, there are many of them to try.

You can also try to put the shellcode in an environment variable.